# Not able to json decode in php

Tags: php, json

i have string like below i am trying to json_decode() it but it gives me empty value

```
{
"products": [{
    "product_id": 6,
    "product_name": "Reusable Baby Cloth Diaper with 5 Layered Baby Insert Pads (Pack of 2), id:(6)",
    "quantity": Reusable Baby Cloth Diaper with 5 Layered Baby Insert Pads (Pack of 2), id:(6),
    "strikeprice": ,"cart_total": 120,"delivery_charge": 10,"delivery_discount": ,"discount": 20,"gullack_discount": 10,"gullack_points_used": 20,"max_points_usable_original": ,"final_price": 200,"gullack_point_win": 200,"product_image": "","referrer": null,"share_points_given": 0,"order_status": 1"max_points_usable":0}],"orderDetails": {"address_id": 406,"phone": "9284759237","payment_mode": ,"successCallbackUrl": "http://localhost:4200/ordersuccess/{orderId}","failedCallbackUrl": "http://localhost:4200/placeorder#paymentFailed","campaign_id": "NA","query": "","offer_id": null,"query_string": ""}
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Paste the JSON into jsonlint.com. It shows a validation error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON is not formatted correctly.

Try using an online json parser, I cleaned up your code, see below, using the following: http://json.parser.online.fr/

```
{
"products":[
{
"product_id":6,
"product_name":"Reusable Baby Cloth Diaper with 5 Layered Baby Insert Pads (Pack of 2), id:(6)",
"quantity":"Reusable Baby Cloth Diaper with 5 Layered Baby Insert Pads (Pack of 2)",
"id":6,
"strikeprice":"",
"cart_total":120,
"delivery_charge":10,
"delivery_discount":"",
"discount":20,
"gullack_discount":10,
"gullack_points_used":20,
"max_points_usable_original":"",
"final_price":200,
"gullack_point_win":200,
"product_image":"",
"referrer":null,
"share_points_given":0,
"order_status":"",
"max_points_usable":0
}
],
"orderDetails":{
"address_id":406,
"phone":"9284759237",
"payment_mode":"",
"successCallbackUrl":"http://localhost:4200/ordersuccess/{orderId}",
"failedCallbackUrl":"http://localhost:4200/placeorder#paymentFailed",
"campaign_id":"NA",
"query":"",
"offer_id":null,
"query_string":""
}
}
```

If you are pulling these values and they are blank, null or zero you want to ensure that you handle that as well.  A few things found:

- Missing quote around quantity value
- Missing quotes around quantity value ID was a string (6) which would need quotes or needs to be changed to just 6
- strike_price missing value delivery discount
- missing value max_points_usable_original missing value payment_mode
- missing value Missing quote around l in order status, also missing
- comma after

I realize that the changes I made to your code will most likely not be what you want.  I would check it against the parser and correct data and structure as you see fit.

Comment: Yeah Working !! Thanks a ton

Answer (score 2):

This part of the JSON is invalid:

```
"quantity": Reusable Baby Cloth Diaper with 5 Layered Baby Insert Pads (Pack of 2), id:(6),
```

I'm not sure why the quantity is a string instead of a number. But since it is, it needs quotes:

```
"quantity": "Reusable Baby Cloth Diaper with 5 Layered Baby Insert Pads (Pack of 2), id:(6)",
```

You should fix the code that's creating the JSON. This type of error would be impossible if it used a JSON library, so it must be constructing the JSON in an ad hoc fashion, and doing it wrong.

Comment: Yeah got it! thanks for help @Barmar